# Write additional jsdoc to parent method

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

In this scenario:

```
class A {
  /**
   * This method does something...
   *
   * @return {void}
   * @throws {TypeError}  If something is wrong
   */
  baseMethod() {
    if (typeof this.baseMethodValidator === 'function') { // Apply only if exists
      this.baseMethodValidator();
    }
    // ...
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    this.baseMethodValidator = function () {
      // ... B validation
    }
  }
}

class C extends A {
  constructor() {
    this.baseMethodValidator = function () {
      // ... C validation
    }
  }
}
```

**Question**: How can I write a jsdoc to explain that `baseMethod` in `B` class requires (for example) and **id** and a **name** and `baseMethod` in `C` requires only an **id** when there's no method in child classes? (all logic is inside parent's `baseMethod`)

Thank you

Comment: Whats the `baseMethodValidator` good for? Why its an instance method and not a class method??

Comment: It's a validator. In this example I'm just trying to simplify what the real code does. Either function will check if back services are good to go (aka, service logger, databases, pipes, ...). Anyway, question is related to documentation. Thanks anyway